# Why java annotation attributes have restrictions?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I noticed that if I create an annotation:

```
public @interface NullableTypeOverride {
    NullableType hibernateTypeOverride();
}
```

I have limited options for annotation attributes. The above code will not work because annotations only take primitive, `String` or `Class` types for their attributes.

So in this case I can't use this annotation like this:

```
@NullableTypeOverride(hibernateTypeOverride = Hibernate.INTEGER)
private Long distance;
```

My guess is that it has something to do with compile time vs. runtime but I'm not entirely sure. So what is the reason for this limitation and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JLS [states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6)

> It is a compile-time error if the return type of a method declared in
>   an annotation type is not one of the following: a primitive type,
>   String, Class, any parameterized invocation of Class, an enum type
>   (§8.9), an annotation type, or an array type (§10) whose element type
>   is one of the preceding types.

The reason for this is that annotations must have a constant value. If you provide a reference to an object that may change, you'll have problems. This is only relevant if the annotation's Retention is `RUNTIME`.

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    Person person();
}

@MyAnnotation(person = ???) // how to guarantee it won't change at runtime?
public void method1()  {...}
```

What's that value supposed to be? And how can reflection libs cache it?

```
MyAnnotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
annotation.person(); // should be the same value every time
```

Remember, annotations are supposed to be metadata.